# how to fix syntaxe error when creating a kafka topic?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a docker image for bigdata, so I run Jupyter from this docker
I want to create a kafka topic using this commande

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --partitions 5 --replication-factor 2 --topic test
```

Unfortunately I got this error message exactly on the localhost:2181:

> File "", line 1
>       kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --partitions 5 --replication-factor 2 --topic test
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The tool to manage topics is called `kafka-topics.sh`. What is the command (`kafka-topics`) that you are using?

Comment: The same error when i use kafka-topics.sh